# Windows Phone 7 Frame Rate Performance

Tags: windows-phone-7

Reading [Jeff Willcox on frame rate counters](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/), I realized my application rarely hit the 60 fps. I'm not satisfied with the global performance of my app (compared to its iPhone counterpart), but the numbers seems weird to me.

When the app is doing nothing, even just after launch, it's even sometimes at 0 fps. And the higher I hit is 50 fps.

Overall, my application is not blazing fast, but not really slow. So how can I interpret the numbers ? **How can I spot the issue that makes my app have a bad fps ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A low frame rate doesn't necessarily indicate poor performance.

If you're testing **on an actual device** and you see poor performance when then an investigation may indicate a problem that may be related to an issue which also impacts frame rate.

Hmmm. That sentence may not be clear.

Don't worry too much about getting a high frame rate all the time. Focus on actual performance experienced by the user.
If the actual performance is poor and the frame rate is low, that's when you should worry about the frame rate.

What's important is testing on an actual device and what performance is like there.

Comment: Exactly. It's be nice if we could keep framerate at 50+ the whole time, but that's not realistic for the overwhelming majority of apps. So perceived performance becomes the goal instead of real performance.

Answer (score 3):

Jeff Wilcox notes in his post that:

> Frame rate counters may be 0 when there is no animation being updated on the thread at any particular moment. You can add a very simple, continually animating and repeating, animation to your application during development & testing if you want to ensure that there is always some frame rate value available.

So the 0fps reading seems not be an issue since no screen updates need to be rendered.